# How to import only the NEW records during Excel-import from SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am currently receiving a push-feed with data into a SQL Server Express database. The feed is updated randomly several times a minute (pushed into the database). I want to import the new updated records into Excel by making a call every three seconds from Excel to the SQL Server database.

I discovered that there are three methods to import the data from SQL Server into Excel:

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

1. import using QueryTable
2. import using ADO
3. import using Add-In

Although with these methods the *complete* table is imported from the database every time. *I only want to import the new added records since the last import* since the SQL Server database becomes very large.

I have two questions:

1)  How can I import only the new added records?

2)  What is the most efficient method regarding speed and system-load from the above three import methods?

Thank you!

Comment: Wow...every three seconds? Depending on the amount of data you may have multiple threads running at the same time. This has a lot of red flags of being a poor design. Sounds to me like Excel is the wrong tool for whatever it is you are trying to do here. You are effectively doubling the network traffic with a process that happens constantly.

Comment: @Sean, thanks Sean, although i need to do it in Excel due to my historical set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is correct to say `Import to Excel`. More correctly would be to say `Export from SQL Server to Excel`. 
There can be few ways to do this. Will rate them from easiest/fastest to complicated/slowest:

1. Easiest one: You add a new column to your SQL table as a "Exported flag" and mark it for all exported columns. So, next time you will be able to export the newest records where value in that column is empty. That column can have type "BIT", "TINYINT" or even "DATETIME" to indicate when that record was exported. The problem with that method only in the case when you are not allowed to add any new columns to the table. Here is sample code to Update flag and extract values in one transaction:

`UPDATE #tbl_TMP
SET Flag = 1
OUTPUT DELETED.A, DELETED.B, DELETED.C
WHERE Flag = 0`

2. If you are not allowed to add new column you might use existing columns in the table. For instance if you have any Time stamp or Incremental value in the table you can record the latest extracted value and all records bigger than stored value will be "newest records to extract".
3. If table does not have Time stamp or Incremental values you can
   create another table, which will contain list of already extracted
   key values from the table. Then by linking these tables you can
   figure out which records are new.
4. If table does not have key value you can store HASH of all or several columns in another table and then link by that HASH to figure out the new ones.

Comment: I am allowed to add a new column and I have incremental values in the table. I will try to write some Excel-VBA code within one of the three  import methods above. I was already thinking in this direction, although I was hoping there would be a standard command already available for this because I am a bit worried that this is quite an intensive process to make a query everytime which has to qualify for every record if it has to be included or excluded in the export? Which is the fastest method of the 4 methods? Thanks.

Comment: Adding TINYINT column and updating it would be the easiest/fastest. See updating query code in the answer. The same query does an update and extracts newest data.

Comment: Thank you. Is this Excel VBA code which i can integrate in the import-code examples from : https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

Comment: Creative idea Slava. I think indeed this is the best solution since the processing to identify the new records stays in the database.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create a linked server to the Excel data.
> 2. Put an INSERT trigger on the SQL Server table to insert all new rows to the spreadsheet

Comment: Are you sure this works for importing into Excel (= exporting from SQL Server)? As I search on the internet, I only can find set ups for queries the other way around: into SQL Server from Excel). Thanks.

Comment: I believe so: http://akawn.com/blog/2012/01/query-and-update-an-excel-2010-spread-sheet-via-a-linked-server/